# Rails: saving filter conditions on attributes and checking whether conditions pass?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, filter

I have a SaaS application where an Account has many Users.

In an Account, the account owner can specify certain filters on the users that are applying to be part of the account. For instance, he can set that these requirement conditions must be met in order for user to be accepted into account : user.age > 21, user.name.count > 4.

I was thinking of creating a FilterCondition model, which belongs to Account, where a row could look like `account_id: 1, attribute: "age", condition_string: "> 21"` or `account_id: 1, attribute: "phone_type", condition_string: "== iphone"`

and then when I want to only accept users that meet these conditions do something like

```
  #User.rb
  def passes_requirements?
    account.filter_conditions.each do |filter_conditions|
      attr = filter_condition.attribute
      return false if self.attr != filter_condition.condition
    end 
    true
  end
```

I know that is completely wrong syntax, but it should get the point across on what I would like to do.

Any suggested ways to allow accounts to save requirement conditions, and then check on Users to see if they meet those requirements?

Answer (score 4):

It will be easier if the condition string is separated into a comparator (e.g `>`) and the value to be compared:

```
class FilterCondition < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :account

  validates :attribute, presence: true
  validates :comparator, presence: true
  validates :value, presence: true

  def matching_users(query_chain = User.where(account: account))
    query_chain.where("#{attribute} #{safe_comparator} ?", value)
  end

  private
  def safe_comparator
    safe_values = ['=', '>', '>=', '<', '<='] # etc
    return comparator if safe_values.include? comparator
    ''
  end
end
```

The `safe_comparator` method reduces the risk of SQL injection into the query. Chaining a collection of filters is a bit tricky, but something like the following idea should work.

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base
  #....
  has_many :filter_conditions
  def filtered_users
    query = User.where(account: self)
    filter_conditions.each do |filter_condition|
      query = filter_condition.matching_users(query)
    end
    query
  end

end


account = Account.first

filter_1 = FilterCondition.create(
  account: account,
  attribute: :age,
  comparator: '>=',
  value: 21
)
filter_2 = FilterCondition.create(
  account: account,
  attribute: :age,
  comparator: '<=',
  value: 99
)


account.filtered_users
```

Comment: Would this work if we wanted to compare strings too? So like "user phone type must be either iPhone or Android" , and it would filter out the users with other phones

Comment: Should do as long as the DB type of `value` in `FilterCondition` is a string. The generated ActiveRecord query would be `where("phone_type = ?", 'iPhone')`. Doing an OR query (e.g either Android or iPhone) is harder and would require a restructure of `FilterCondition` (but not impossible)

Comment: query_chain.where("#{attribute} #{safe_comparator} ?", value) => I don't think #{safe_comparator} actually turns into a comparator. It is still a string type. Is there any way we could do #{safe_comparator.to_comparator} or something like that?

Comment: It's meant to be a string. Essentially you're sending in a Arel/ActiveRecord query string along with a bunch of values. The question marks are then substituted with the values in a sql-safe way and the whole string is turned into a SQL query.

Comment: This is the solution that we ended up coming up with: https://gist.github.com/kibaekr/64908308ba189680cc49